# About a Cuban VISA that can't be stuck on the passport

Tags: visas, passports, cuba

I've asked the Cuban consulate the VISA for a 2 weeks holiday (I'm from The Netherlands).

They sent me the VISA by mail. I'm surprised to see that it can't be stuck on the passport pages (it is not a sticky paper). Should I just insert it into my passport without sticking it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like what you have is a "Tourist Card".

There is no need to stick this into your passport - just keep it with your passport when entering Cuba and during your stay.

When entering Cuba they will normally not stamp your passport itself (although they will if you ask), but will instead stamp the tourist card. When exiting the country they will collect the tourist card.

If you are an American citizen then you should make sure they do NOT stamp your passport, as Americans are forbidden from visiting Cuba under most circumstances.  If you are from another country then there should be no issue if you get them to stamp the passport, even if you intend to visit the US in the future.

Comment: Thanks very much: one more thing... can I leave my passport in my hotel in cuba and walk around with a copy of it (so i dont risk to lose it) ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have what I knew as a loose leaf visa.  They're commonly issued by countries that have other countries that don't like their stamps.

The examples I'm aware of that do this are South Africa (in the Apartheid era, they don't do it anymore), Israel and Cuba.